# how to use associations in view font-end use angularjs and rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, associations

I am using Rails 4 write in back-end and angular js to write front end. I have a trouble to use associations.

I have two models:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :records
end
```

I am using model `records_tags` to connect two models `Record` and `Tag`.

In controller, I write:

```
def index
   records = Record.all.order('created_at DESC')
   render json: {error:0, data: records}
end
```

In view

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat ="data in datas"> {{data.tags.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Although, I use relationship in controller success, but variable datas i send to view I don't use relationship them.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats normal, When you are in controller `data` is a collection on ActiveModel objects, so relations are live within it. But when you export as json you are sending only json object. To include `tags` with `records` you have to include `tags` in the `json` object.

```
def index
  records = Record.all.order('created_at DESC')
  render json: {error:0, data: records.as_json(include: :tags))}
end
```